Enable "forgot password" option on login page
I use apache superset in my company and we have to many requests of password reseting. At the moment, the only option we have for doing it is asking the tool administrator to do it.We would like to have a "forgot password" feature.
It seems that it is possible to enable a feature "forgot password" on login page. I have searched everywhere but couldn't find this info. Does anyone knows how to enable this feature so the user itself can reset its password?

Were you able to find a solution to this problem ? I am running into similar issue. Ty
